# Use static_assert to ensure template parameter is only used *at most* once

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, static-assert

Is it possible to ensure a certain template parameter (or combination of template parameters) is used - at most - once?  Would it be possible to track the number of times it's used, and throw a static_assert error if it was used more than once?

As an example - let's say I wanted to create a static, template-based GPIO class:

```
template<uint8_t Port, uint8_t Pin> class Gpio {};
```

One could feasibly lay out their entire board in a single Board class:

```
struct Board {
  Gpio<1, 1> myInputPin;
  Gpio<1, 2> myOutputPin;

  Gpio<2, 0> ledR;
  Gpio<2, 1> ledG;
  Gpio<2, 2> ledB;
};
```

For any given port/pin combination, it only makes sense for a *single* GPIO template to be instantiated for that port and pin.  If someone creates two different GPIO instances for the same port/pin combination, it likely represents a conflict, and I would like to catch this error during compilation.

Is this possible?

Comment: So you have a class, for example, `Gpio<1, 2>`, and want to ensure that only a single object of this class exists? Sounds like you want to use the singleton anti pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem with a macro:

```
#define GPIO(Port, Pin) \
    friend void _gpio_ ## Port ## _ ## Pin(){} \
    Gpio<Port, Pin>
```

Then if you use `GPIO(2, 2)` twice, the compiler will say something like this:

```
error: redefinition of '_gpio_2_2'
  GPIO(2, 2) ledX;
  ^

<source>:14:3: note: previous definition is here
  GPIO(2, 2) ledB;
  ^
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/ronV0u

Comment: This only prevents instantiating the class multiple times within the same scope. You can still create as many `Gpio<X, Y>` objects as you want if you spread them accross multiple classes / functions.

Comment: @pschill: Fair point, I've updated my answer to protect against that as well.